# Allow Referential Integrity To Update and Delete

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on this web application and am using MySQL DB, and I have so many tables referencing one another.

When I make updates or deletes from the table, I have to look into every table that have the reference ID to either update or delete to prevent data inconsistency.

But now with so many tables the process has become very cumbersome, and I was wondering if it would be a good idea to allow the referential integrity to do the updates and deletes across all the tables referencing the ID.

My Question is,is it a good idea to totally allow the system handle all the operations

Answer (score 0):

Using InnoDB as engine, you can set which action to do (UPDATE or DELETE) between foreign keys and their references easily.

Comment: Yeah I know this, but is it a good idea to totally allow the system handle all the operations

Comment: Indeed, you can rollback if anything goes wrong during the process